# Rails find a date that is equal to to between two dates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a sales table that has a sale_date field. I also have a start_date and end_date for each month as a 'sales month' for example can start on 25th of june and end on the 26 of july rather than just being a calendar month.

I want to find all sales between ( and including ) the two dates but I can't figure it out.

```
user = User.last
user.sales.where( sale_date is within start_date...end_date )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this please

```
 user = User.last
 user.sales.where(sale_date: start_date..end_date )
```

it will replicate in sql as `BETWEEN '#start_date' AND '#end_date'`

or you can try this if you want query to use DATE and including = check.

```
 user.sales.where("DATE(sale_date) >= ? AND DATE(sale_date) <= ?", start_date, end_date )
```

Comment: I need it to be between including the two dates

Answer (score 0):

```
user.sales.where("sale_date >= ? AND sale_date <= ?", start_date, end_date )
```